# Change Div Color When Clicking Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change `div` color when clicking checkbox by assigning a function for `onchange`. I get `null` for both `var div` id and `var checkbox` in the function. Am I missing something? Or is there any way to do this only by using CSS?

```js
function check(cbid,id) {
 var div = document.getElementById(id);
 var checkbox = document.getElementById(cbid);
 console.log(div);
 console.log(checkbox);
 if(checkbox.checked == true) {
  div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 } else {
  div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
 }
}
```

```css
.excluded-prices {
 min-height: 55px;
 padding: 13px 0 0 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 clear: left;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 background: #f5fbf5;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.excluded-prices:hover {
 background-color: white;
}

.excluded-prices .ep-checkbox {
 padding: 0 13px 0 0;
 margin-left: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.ep-checkbox .epc {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

excluded-prices .ep-name {
 width: 240px;
 float: left;
}

.epn-title {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #003580; 
}

.epn-description {
 margin-left: 35px;
 padding: 8px 0 13px 0;
 display: block;
 font-size: .923em;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #537bb4;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ep-price {
 display: none;
 float: right;
 margin-top: -45px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.epp-total {
 width: 90px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.total-title {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 3px 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.eppt-price {
 color: #0898ff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 3px 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="excluded-prices" id="internet">
        <div class="ep-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbinternet" onchange="check(cbinternet,internet)" class="epc">
        </div>
        <div class="ep-name">
            <label class="epn-title">Internet(Cable)</label>
            <label class="epn-description">Internet is available for the entire property and costs &euro; 14 per
                day.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ep-price">
            <input type="hidden" id="ep_price">
            <div class="epp-total">
                <p class="total-title">Total</p>
                <p class="eppt-price">BAM 28</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: change your on change into onchange="check('cbinternet','internet')

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to pass String values to your `check` function. So just add quotes like that:

```
onchange="check('cbinternet','internet')"
```

Or :

```
onchange="check(this.id, 'internet')"
```

```js
function check(cbid,id) {
 var div = document.getElementById(id);
 var checkbox = document.getElementById(cbid);
 console.log(div);
 console.log(checkbox);
 if(checkbox.checked == true) {
  div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 } else {
  div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
 }
}
```

```css
.excluded-prices {
 min-height: 55px;
 padding: 13px 0 0 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 clear: left;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 background: #f5fbf5;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.excluded-prices:hover {
 background-color: white;
}

.excluded-prices .ep-checkbox {
 padding: 0 13px 0 0;
 margin-left: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.ep-checkbox .epc {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

excluded-prices .ep-name {
 width: 240px;
 float: left;
}

.epn-title {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #003580; 
}

.epn-description {
 margin-left: 35px;
 padding: 8px 0 13px 0;
 display: block;
 font-size: .923em;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #537bb4;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ep-price {
 display: none;
 float: right;
 margin-top: -45px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.epp-total {
 width: 90px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.total-title {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 3px 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.eppt-price {
 color: #0898ff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 3px 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="excluded-prices" id="internet">
        <div class="ep-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbinternet" onchange="check(this.id, 'internet')" class="epc">
        </div>
        <div class="ep-name">
            <label class="epn-title">Internet(Cable)</label>
            <label class="epn-description">Internet is available for the entire property and costs &euro; 14 per
                day.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ep-price">
            <input type="hidden" id="ep_price">
            <div class="epp-total">
                <p class="total-title">Total</p>
                <p class="eppt-price">BAM 28</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How could I miss it... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You're missing single quotes:

```
check('cbinternet','internet')
```

Comment: I can't believe how I missed this.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake here:

```
onchange="check('cbinternet','internet')"
```

Element id must be a string. Now you are passing null object.

```js
function check(cbid,id) {
 var div = document.getElementById(id);
 var checkbox = document.getElementById(cbid);
 console.log(div);
 console.log(checkbox);
 if(checkbox.checked == true) {
  div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 } else {
  div.style.backgroundColor = "black";
 }
}
```

```css
.excluded-prices {
 min-height: 55px;
 padding: 13px 0 0 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 clear: left;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 background: #f5fbf5;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.excluded-prices:hover {
 background-color: white;
}

.excluded-prices .ep-checkbox {
 padding: 0 13px 0 0;
 margin-left: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.ep-checkbox .epc {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

excluded-prices .ep-name {
 width: 240px;
 float: left;
}

.epn-title {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #003580; 
}

.epn-description {
 margin-left: 35px;
 padding: 8px 0 13px 0;
 display: block;
 font-size: .923em;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #537bb4;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ep-price {
 display: none;
 float: right;
 margin-top: -45px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.epp-total {
 width: 90px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.total-title {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 3px 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.eppt-price {
 color: #0898ff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 3px 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="excluded-prices" id="internet">
        <div class="ep-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="cbinternet" onchange="check('cbinternet','internet')" class="epc">
        </div>
        <div class="ep-name">
            <label class="epn-title">Internet(Cable)</label>
            <label class="epn-description">Internet is available for the entire property and costs &euro; 14 per
                day.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ep-price">
            <input type="hidden" id="ep_price">
            <div class="epp-total">
                <p class="total-title">Total</p>
                <p class="eppt-price">BAM 28</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I should have known what! Thank you for your help.